# Submit form and cordova functions are not getting called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angular-controller

When I try to call the ng-submit - submitForm() function, I am unable to call the function and it doesn't do anything. How do I resolve it?

```css
(function () {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * @ngdoc function
   * @name app.controller:MainCtrl
   * @description
   * # MainCtrl
   * Controller of the app
   */
  angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'cordova', function ($scope, cordova) {
      console.log("Hello...");
      cordova.ready.then(function () {
            alert('Cordova is ready');
            console.log("Ready....");
      });
      // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
      this.submitForm = function() {
        console.log("Submit form...");
        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
            alert('our form is amazing');
            console.log("For submitted..")
        }
      };
  }]); 
  
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I will presume the `cordova.ready` is working but it will only be resolved when your app is running either in an emulator or in a physical device.

I suggest to check if cordova is ready inside the `this.submitForm` method.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'cordova', function ($scope, cordova) {
      console.log("Hello...");

      // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
      this.submitForm = function() {
        console.log("Submit form...");
        cordova.ready.then(function () {
            alert('Cordova is ready');
            console.log("Ready....");
            validateAndSendForm();
        }, function() {
            console.log('It is not cordova, decide to send or not the form.');
            // validateAndSendForm();
        });
      };
      function validateAndSendForm() {
        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
            alert('our form is amazing');
            console.log("For submitted..")
        }
      }
  }]); 

})();
```

Your html should looks something like:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <form method="post" ng-submit="main.submitForm()">
    <!-- More fields here -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have it in app.js as - (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
        .config(config);
        

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controllerAs: 'main'
            })

            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }

})();

Comment: Great @Smitha, then this: `ng-controller="MainCtrl as main"` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see if you're using the 'Controller as' syntax, but otherwise, you have to add the submitForm function to the scope:

$scope.submitForm = function...

Comment: I have it in app.js as - (function () { 'use strict'; angular .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']) .config(config); config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider']; function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { $routeProvider .when('/', { controller: 'MainCtrl', templateUrl: 'views/main.html', controllerAs: 'main' }) .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); } })();